# how to flick and scroll horizontally

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, core-animation

I am trying to do something similar to  http://www.winktoolkit.org/previews/63/

As you can see from the youtube video, It has three section I need to do two only.

So the idea is there will be bunch of images divided into two sections and both the sections can be scrolled horizontally by just flicking just like iphone photo app, you see an image and flick it you see another image, you can flick backward and forward. To be more specific, I have put an image of the wireframe that I am working on

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/PZ-3H3VEujd7b2w9V3UJlJSL2rubFpkbdgdHPXy8M2Q?feat=directlink

EDIT: I should also be able to find out, which image the user has taped on, based on that I have to take some action, for example a detail page.

Thanks for your help.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to code it in Objective-C, you need a `UIScrollView` and set it's property `pagingEnabled` to YES and the property `contentSize` to *widthOfOnePage*numberOfPages*.

To get the "bullets" you need a `UIPageControl`. Keep in mind that the `UIPageControl` does not get updated automatically but you can use the `UIScrollView delegate method` `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` to update the active bullet in the `UIPageControl`.

For getting the image the user tapped on, use the `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method.

Comment: Thanks, let me check this out.

Answer (score 1):

The video looks like its a webpage. You might want to consider have a tableview with scrollviews in each row

To detemine which image has been pressed you can add each image as a button not just a standard image and tag each button

Set the delegate of the button and handle the button press, pull out the tag and deal with it

Comment: I agree with @JFoulkes, thats very easy way of doing it.But the video u shared has bullets in the bottom that effect u can get with page control only

Comment: Hi JFoulkes, I have edited the question, so how do I know which image is been clicked on the scroll view of a row.

Answer (score 1):

U can use page control.They are also using page control in the video.

Comment: Swastik, isn't it page control is what iphone photo app uses, does it has an option to split the screen into two section, any way I will try and take a look at it.

Comment: @Yogesh, please specify what exactaly u want to do, just simply scrolling horizontally?

Comment: sorry I wasn't very clear, the bullets at the bottom is what I don't need, if you see the jpg link that I posted it shows clearly how it will look like. Thanks, for the suggestion though